# how to test if a Play Enumerator has no data

Tags: scala, playframework, enumerator, loops

What's the simplest way of checking if a Play `Enumerator` has no data to push? E.g. if it is based on a empty file or was simply created like this:

```
val noData = Enumerator()
```

Do I have to use `Enumeratee` and `Await` or is there a simple one-liner? Just to be clear, I don't want to consume data if it's not empty.

Comment: There is no way to know without consuming data from the Enumerator. Is there a reason you can't handle the empty enumerator case when you are consuming input?

Comment: I thought there's a way you can `peek` at it. There's a point in the middle of the logic, where it would be handy to examine the Enumerator before passing it on.

Comment: There might be some weird thing you could do like taking off the first element, making sure it isn't EOF then making a new `Enumerator` using this element and the previous enumerator. I'm not sure how well that would work. You would have to play with it.